# Capacitor discharging total charge calculation

Tags: capacitor

I need to estimate the total charge that flowed from the capacitor for a short duration of 2ms. I am using an ATmega128 for this. Can someone advise me if analog sample/hold in front of an ADC is applicable for this? Or some other analog solution perhaps? I am not very familiar with this measurement procedure. Please see this picture:

[image]

sch;
[image]

Comment: Hi! Can you please add a schematic of your circuit and add some insights of what is happening exactly? You say you want to use an ADC but that is a current plot, while usually ADCs measure voltage. I find your question quite confusing, please improve it.

Comment: The charge is the integral of current over the time. But, please give us more info about your setup.

Comment: You want to use a "coulomb counter" for this.

Comment: @Vladimir, yes that after we convert current to voltage.

Comment: @Ignacio, can coulomb counter work at this high speed?

Comment: 2ms is not an high speed...

Comment: Do as Andy suggests and take two samples of the capacitor voltage with the ADC and use `Q=CV`. Otherwise, if you know the capacitor initial charge and discharge path, you could integrate the discharge equation `Vs*e^(-t/RC)` and compute the result at compile-time (assuming this will have something to do with an MCU). It depends on the accuracy you need.

Comment: @Dirceu, I am exploring it so no circuit at the moment.

Comment: @sherrellbc, Its not that easy , usually its done with a very high speed ADC/DSP and a waveform log is stored in memory and analized. I dont have capacitance value and also I am looking for analog solution but discharge pulse profiles can vary so this is the catch.

Comment: Do you know what resistance you are discharging through?

Comment: @ThePhoton, The resistor selected at present is 80 Ohm.

Comment: Do you know this is a simple RC circuit (please share your schematic so we'll know too)? Then you can estimate the time constant from the chart, and use that to determine C.

Comment: @ThePhoton, It is R-C-and a shorting switch simple.

Comment: It is much more clear if you share an actual schematic. Even something as simple as an RC has room for ambiguity if you do not show the schematic.

Comment: I liked the integrator solution of the OP Adi.
Be careful resetting the cap, some charge can leak in.
And as @Spehro Pefhany said, minimal DC offsets.

Comment: @ThePhoton, Please find the attached sch.

Answer (score 3):

Q = CV so the loss of charge is also proportional to the loss of voltage (providing there isn't a recharge path that might be bolstering up the voltage).

If you know the capacitance then the the calculation is very straightforward.

Using a sample and hold (and ADC) that measures initial voltage (converts to digital and stores it) then measures final voltage (2 milli seconds later) and stores it is pretty much a normal sort of setup for analogue to digital converters. Virtually any off-the-shelf successive-approximation ADCs from TI, ADI, Maxim, NXP and Linear tech will fit the bill providing it has enough accuracy but that is delving into another area not covered in your question.

Comment: The capacitance is not known, what I can do is charge /discharge it with a square wave.If I measure Initial and final voltage only I wont be getting the entire time integral. The slope is not linear and I need precise measurement.

Comment: If you do not know the capacitance then do you have a method for measuring current? If so, you could charge the capacitor to peak and then discharge and sample the discharge current. After this you could use `Q=I*t` and approximate the integral of the discharge curve you sampled.

Comment: @sherrellbc,Say I convert and get an equivalent voltage response for my current pulse discharge . I am using atmega128 as mentioned earlier it won't sample this waveform I guess. Is there an analog solution ?, which could integrate this pulse and we can read its value after  or 1 or 2 millisecond interval.

Comment: @Adi, sampling the voltage would work if you know the current as well which would simply be V/R if you have the cap discharging through a known resistor.

Comment: Who is the meanie downvoter - maybe you're not mean - maybe there is something flawed in what I said and, if you told me I could fix it. On the other hand, if you despised me, you wouldn't tell me LOL.

Comment: @Andyaka, +1 are you suspecting  sherrellbc LOL .

Comment: @Adi - I have no suspicions at all.

Comment: @Andyaka, Probably not a down voting but a vote undo, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious way to measure charge is to measure the voltage across your 80\$\Omega\$ resistor with the ADC and integrate numerically using one of the time-proven algorithms (trapezoidal rule, for example).

If I read correctly, the ATMega128 ADC can run only at about 15ksps, so you'd only have about 30 samples over your 2ms pulse length. Each measurement will be smeared a bit by the ADC acquisition time, so the accuracy would be somewhat limited.

Another potential issue is that you would have to make sure to throw away most of the data before and after the trigger occurs, because otherwise any offset in the ADC measurement would be integrated as well and would grow without bound as time goes on. Setting a threshold for integration might be a (slightly sloppy) way to work that.

If you want to use this kind of method, an external ADC or a different processor with  a built-in ADC that runs at (say) 200ksps might be more appropriate.

Comment: Can an opamp Integrator solution work for this , can I expect approx 2% accuracy?.

Comment: Absolutely, you'd just have to control the beginning and end times (similar to the digital method) to minimize the errors due to offset then measure the voltage at the end. A precision op-amp would likely result in much higher accuracy.

Comment: Hi, I find the Integrator O/P voltage is showing a slope(not stable) and sometimes at fast discharge it shows a kind of oscillatory behaviour totally absurd.I use simple opamp integrator with 15pf feedback capacitor .Any insight? .External ADC 200Ksps will not be compatible with my ATMega128.

Comment: @Adi suggest you open another question for this and show the schematic you're using (including op-amp part number and supplies).

Answer (score 1):

You know the initial current is 5000 uA, through 80 ohms. That means the initial capacitor voltage is 400 mV.

You can also estimate the time constant from your I(t) curve. By eye, I estimate it's about 0.3 ms. Assuming you have the actual data, you can estimate it much more accurately.

Since the time constant is 0.3 ms, you can now estimate the capacitance is about 3.75 uF.

Since you know the capacitance and voltage, you now know the initial charge, which is about 1.5 uC.

Since your discharge time is around 6.7x the time consant, you've discharged nearly the entire initial charge, or 1.5 uC. The error in this approximation is less than 0.2%, which is probably more accurately than you know the resistor value. Even if you choose a precision resistor, this error is probably less than the error in estimating the time constant (which isn't an easy fitting problem).

Comment: Actually I dont have the I(t) curve , this is what I need to measure or Log . I know the Initial value of current, The final Value of current and Resistance connected.